# Is there any way to read data of grid view of user control, from parent page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, user-controls

I'm getting grid view:

```
var txtName = document.getElementById('<%=ucAddressDetail.FindControl("gvAdress").ClientID %>');

$('#<%=(ucAddressDetail.FindControl("gvAdress")).ClientID%> tr:has(td)').each(function () {
                var rowCount = $("[id*=gvAdress] td").closest("tr").length;
                if (rowCount > 0) {
                    var txtAddresstype = this.document.getElementById("txtAddressType");
                    var txtAddress1 = $(this).find("txtAddress1");
                    var txtAddress2 = $(this).find("txtAddress2");
                    var txtPostalCode = $(this).find("txtPostalCode");
                    var txtCountry = $(this).find("txtCountry");
                    var txtState = $(this).find("txtState");
                    var txtDistrict = $(this).find("txtDistrict");
                    var txtCity = $(this).find("txtCity");


                    var objAddress = {
                        Addresstype: txtAddresstype.val(),
                        Address1: txtAddress1.val(),
                        Address2: txtAddress2.val(),
                        PostalCode: txtPostalCode.val(),
                        Country: txtCountry.val(),
                        State: txtState.val(),
                        District: txtDistrict.val(),
                        City: txtCity.val(),
                    }
```

Comment: and, where is the question?

Comment: question Is how to  read data of grid view which is in user control, and to read it from parent page using jQuery,